# FusionChart with only one time range

Tags: javascript, format, fusioncharts

I´m use fusionChart for show a graphics, I want graphics only in this format 03/04/2022 00:20 , 03/04/2022 00:40 ... but when change the size of graphic change the format time, any idea for the format time always the same??

[image]

Becasue when change the size of my screen , the time change

[image]

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can customize the output time format for each time unit by specifying date-time tokens for respective time format.

```
    "xAxis": {
    outputTimeFormat: {
        //year: "",
        month: "%b'%y (%q)",
        day: "%d/%m (%a)",
        //hour: "",
        //minute: "",
        //second: "",
        //millisecond: ""
    }
}
```

To know more about this feature please refer - https://www.fusioncharts.com/dev/fusiontime/getting-started/output-time-format

https://www.fusioncharts.com/dev/fusiontime/fusiontime-attributes#date-time-format

I hope it will help you out, if not please share your case in sample fiddle.